# Error con useState "x is not a function" react

Tags: reactjs, modal

tengo un useState el cual deberia hacer un switch entre true o false para desplegar un modal pero resulta que cuando ejecuto la funcion que cambia el switch del setState me da un error y me dice lo siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: setIsVisibleModal is not a function

la funcion deberia hacer un switch de false a true cuando se ejecuta a traves de la funcion de flecha del onClick en el button, he intentado de todo pero nada funciona, agradeceria saber el porque no me deja cambiar el setState a través de la funcion editUser dentro del onClick.

mi código es este:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {Switch, List, Avatar, Button} from 'antd';
    import Modal from '../../../Modal';

    export default function ListUsers(props){
        const {usersActive, usersInactive} = props;
        const [viewUsersActives, setViewUsersActive] = useState(true);
        const [isVisibleModal, setIsVisibleModal] = useState(false);
        const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState("");
        const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null);
    
        return (
            <div className="list-users">
                <div className="list-users__switch">
                    <Switch 
                    defaultChecked
                    onChange={() => setViewUsersActive(!viewUsersActives)}
                    />
                    <span>
                        {viewUsersActives ? "Usuarios Activos" : "Usuarios Inactivos"}
                    </span>
                </div>
    
                {viewUsersActives ? ( <UsersActive 
                            usersActive={usersActive}
                            setIsVisible={setIsVisibleModal}
                            setModalTitle={setModalTitle}
                            setModalContent={setModalContent}
                />
                
                ):( <UsersInactive usersInactive={usersInactive}/>)}
                <Modal
                    title={modalTitle}
                    isVisible={isVisibleModal}
                    setIsVisible={setIsVisibleModal}
                >
                    {modalContent}
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    function UsersActive(props){
    
        const {usersActive, setIsVisibleModal, setModalTitle, setModalContent} = props;
    
        const editUser = user => {
           /*Acá ocurre el error =>*/ setIsVisibleModal(true);
            setModalTitle(`Editar ${user.name} ${user.lastName}`);
            setModalContent("Editando un usuario");
        };
    
        return(
            <List
            className="users-active"
            itemLayout="horizontal"
            dataSource={usersActive}
            renderItem={user => (
                <List.Item
                    actions={[
                        <Button
                        type="primary"
 /*Cuando se ejecuta este onClick =>*/onClick={() => editUser(user)}
                        >
                            <EditOutlined />
                        </Button>,
                        <Button
                        type="warning"
                        onClick={() => console.log("Desactivar Usuario")}>
                            <StopOutlined />
                        </Button>,
                        <Button
                        type="danger"
                        onClick={() => console.log("Eliminar Usuario")}
                        >
                            <DeleteOutlined />
                        </Button>
                    ]}
                >
                    <List.Item.Meta
                    avatar={<Avatar src={user.avatar ? user.avatar: NoAvatar}/>}
                    title={`
                        ${user.name ? user.name : '...'}
                        ${user.lastName ? user.lastName : '...'}
                    `}
                    description={user.email}
                    />
                </List.Item>
            )}
            />
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que se está **usando la referencia equivocada**, el handler se llama `setIsVisibleModal` y se esta pasando como `setIsVisible` al componente `UsersActive`:

```
<UsersActive 
        usersActive={usersActive}
        setIsVisible={setIsVisibleModal}
        setModalTitle={setModalTitle}
        setModalContent={setModalContent}
/>
```

Luego, en el componente `UsersActive`, al destructurar el objeto `props`, se busca por una referencia que no existe, `setIsVisibleModal`:

```
//setIsVisibleModal no viene en props, le asignaste el nombre setIsVisible
const {usersActive, setIsVisibleModal, setModalTitle, setModalContent} = props;
```

Cuando se intenta llamar a `setIsVisibleModal`, React indica que eso no es una función:

```
 /*Acá ocurre el error =>*/ setIsVisibleModal(true);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: setIsVisibleModal is not a function

Hay que verificar el uso de los nombres de las `props`, tal como se declararon desde el parent, en este caso para el componente `UsersActive` (y los demás Leaf/child components que requieran `state as props` en el árbol de componentes):

```
 //pseudocódigo
 const {setIsVisible, ... } = props;
 //...codigo
 /*ya no debe haber error =>*/ setIsVisible(true);
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Pues sí, resulta que entre el sueño y el estrés no me había dado cuenta que lo había renombrado mal y por ese mismo motivo el prop no estaba leyendo bien, muchas gracias por la respuesta ^^

Comment: Si se me hizo raro, pues tenias todas las props bien menos esta, a mí también me pasa seguido XD, saludos